# Как удалить кавычки из файла json

Tags: javascript, python, json

Есть код создания JSON файла

```
def search_message(text):
    js = vk.messages.search(q=text)
    js = "data = " + str(js)
    with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(js ,json_file, indent=2)
```

т.к. это строка, то у неё в начале и в конце есть двойные кавычки, а для чтения данного файла JS'ом они мешаются.

Как убрать кавычки?

Answer (score 3):

### Полагаю, что Вы немного заблуждаетесь. Поправьте меня, если я ошибусь.

Вот здесь (в переменной js) вы получаете словарь (или список словарей):

```py
js = vk.messages.search(q=text)
```

Что-то типа вот такого:

```py
[
    {
        'a': 1,
        'b': 2
    }
]
# Или такого
{
    'a': 1,
    'b': 2
}
```

#### Тепер что делаете Вы:

```py
js = "data = " + str(js)
```

> Тоесть Вы берете, преобразуете нормальный объект к его строковому выражению, создаете объект который ничего обще с json не имеет, объединяя это все со строкой `'data = '`

#### Я бы сделал так (если бы хотел задампить в файл результат запроса)

```py
def search_message(text):
    js = vk.messages.search(q=text)
    with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(js ,json_file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Если Вам нужен JSON типа:

```json
{
  "data": {
        "a": 1,
        "b": 2
    }
}
```

Вы можете сделать так:

```py
def search_message(text):
    js = vk.messages.search(q=text)
    with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump({'data':js} ,json_file, indent=2, ensure_ascii=False)
```

#### UPD

Поскольку в переменной `js` могут оказаться данные типа `datetime` которые `json` не умеет интерпретировать, то желательно к вашему конструктору добавить обработчик неизвестных типов данных. В результате мы получим

```py
from datetime import datetime, date
import json


def handler(val):
    if isinstance(val, (datetime, date)):
        return val.isoformat()


def search_message(text):
    js = vk.messages.search(q=text)
    with open('data.json', 'w') as json_file:
        json.dump(
            {'data': js},
            json_file,
            indent=2,
            # На случай если в данных есть не ascii символы
            # к примеру кириллица и вам нужны читаемые символы в дампе
            ensure_ascii=False,
            default=handler
        )
```

#### UUPD

Если же в файле Вам действительно нужно содержимое типа

```json
data = {
  "a": 1,
  "b": 2
}
```

то порекомендую соорудить что-то вот такое:

```py
js_data = json.dumps(
                      js, 
                      indent=2
                      # Далее параметры на Ваше успотерие из вышеперечисленных
)
file_content = f'data = {js_data}'

with open('data.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    file.write(
        file_content
    )
```

Answer (score -4):

Присвойте то, что внутри ковычек в переменную

```
test = 'My table'
```